# Quarantined root directory on primary drive?

Tags: macos, extended-attributes

I've been experiencing performance issues on my mid-2011 mac mini (running El Cap) for a while now -- beachballs, spotlight issues, general slowness -- and have been so far unable to discern the actual cause (this is, in part, why I haven't yet upgraded to Sierra). I just noticed that the root of my primary drive is marked as quarantined:

```
andy@Aurora[14:57:14]: $ ls -ldeO@ /
drwxr-xr-x@ 40 root  wheel  - 1428 Jan  7 16:20 /
    com.apple.quarantine      68
```

Is it possible that this is the cause of my problems? And how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else I would strongly recommend you backing up all your files and (after that) double checking for malware on your Mac.

You can remove the com.apple.quarantine attribute with `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /`.
For a more in-depth explaination of the com.apple.quarantine extended attribute, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104875/212614).