# com.apple.quarantine attribute does not cause any warnings

Tags: launch-services

I've read in several places I've found via search that quarantine flag results in a warning when app is tried to be run (and then flag is cleared):
https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine

> it can ask for user confirmation the first time the downloaded program
>   is run, to help stop malware. Upon confirmation the attribute should
>   be removed automatically, and then the program will run normally.

[What causes OS X to mark a folder as Quarantined?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104712/what-causes-os-x-to-mark-a-folder-as-quarantined)

> When the Launch Services API is used to open a quarantined file and
>   the file appears to be an application, script, or other executable
>   file type, Launch Services will display an alert to confirm the user
>   understands the file is some kind of application.

However on my MacBook (MacOS Mojave):

```
xattr -l /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
com.apple.quarantine: 01c1;5d958e46;Chrome;D01EADC9-90F1-4DAB-81A0-A96722A65A11
```

but I can run that app in command line with `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker` and it works w/out warning. I also start Docker.app via Command-Space without warning now, but

```
xattr -l /Applications/Docker.app
com.apple.quarantine: 01c1;5d958e46;Chrome;D01EADC9-90F1-4DAB-81A0-A96722A65A11
```

Why I have `com.apple.quarantine` attribute (not cleared already) but it has apparently no effect?

Answer (score 1):

Special attributes cleared when I finished install of new version of `docker desktop` (I stumbled upon the `@` in `ls -l` output when new version was being downloaded). Apparently during download and install some tech details were under the hood and I did not guess they effected main/active file attributes.